# Prove identity based on binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} {2n-1 \choose r} = 2^{2n-2} $

Perhaps it can be proved by using sum of all combinations from r=0 to r=n is 2 to the power of n.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941857/problem-proving-sum-r-0n-1-binom2n-1r-22n-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$ 2\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{r} = \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \left[\binom{2n-1}{r} + \binom{2n-1}{2n-1-r}\right]. $$

Comment: But how to relate the 2n-1 and the n-1?

Comment: I gave you a hint, now it's your turn to continue thinking.